# What's the efficient numerical method to calculate the steady state of many-body quantum open systems?

Tags: computational-physics, many-body, open-quantum-systems

I need to calculate the steady state of many-body quantum open system in cavity with Hamiltonian:
$$H=\frac{g}{\sqrt{N}}\alpha \sum^{N}_{i=1} (b_i a+b_i^\dagger a^\dagger )+\frac{g}{\sqrt{N}}(1-\alpha) \sum^{N}_{i=1} (b_i a^\dagger+b_i^\dagger a )+C_6\sum_{<i,j>} n_i n_j-(\mu a^\dagger a +(\mu+\Delta) \sum_{i=1}^N b_i^{\dagger} b_i)+E (a+a^{\dagger})$$ and collapse operator with spontaneous emission term and photon leakage term.

(It's a 1D Rydberg atom chain. In which $a^{\dagger}$ and $a$ are annihilation and creation operator of photons,  $n_i$,$b_i$ and $b_i^{\dagger}$ are particle number， annihilation and creation operators of Rydberg atoms on ith position.)

I tried to use the package **qutip** but limited by memory,the method could only calculate 4-5 atoms on my PC, but I need to calculate at least 8-10 atoms and clarify its phase diagram.

I want to know if there is any frequently-used and efficient packages or algorithm to deal with such problems. Thanks a lot if you help me!

Comment: Please explain what the terms in the Hamiltonian represent.

Comment: sorry I'd overlooked it. I've edited the question and added the explanation

Comment: ...and what is $n_i$?